# Tenor API search varied results

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm making a Discord bot. Currently where if you type `-gif **arguments**` it uses the Tenor API and posts the result of the gif within a message which does work currently fine, but it always gives me the same result with the same search query. My code is below, so how would I make it to where I could vary the search results of a search with the same query?

```
const Tenor = require("tenorjs").client({
    "Key": "Ihaveakeyjustnotshowingit", // https://tenor.com/developer/keyregistration
    "Filter": "off", // "off", "low", "medium", "high", not case sensitive
    "Locale": "en_US", // Your locale here, case-sensitivity depends on input
    "MediaFilter": "minimal", // either minimal or basic, not case sensitive
    "DateFormat": "MM/D/YYYY - H:mm:ss A" // Change this accordingly
});

const fs = require('fs');
const discord = require('discord.js');


module.exports = {
    name: 'gif',
    aliases: ['tenor', 'gifsearch', 'gf'],
    category: 'Funny',
    utilisation: '{prefix}gif',

    execute(client, message, args) {

        const msgArgs = message.content.slice(this.name.length + 1)

        Tenor.Search.Query(msgArgs, "1").then(Results => {
            Results.forEach(Post => {
                message.channel.send(Post.itemurl)
            });
      }).catch(console.error);
    },
};
```

Comment: What is the actual issue? Is it that the gif/image is always/often same?

Comment: The result of the gif is always the same exact gif, while I want it to do something like randomly choosing one of the top 10 gifs for the given keyword or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Tenor.Search.Query(msgArgs, '10').then(Results => {
             var totalResponses = Results.length;
             var responseIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1) % totalResponses;
             var responseFinal = Results[responseIndex];
            message.channel.send(responseFinal.itemurl)
    }).catch(console.error);
}
```

Request 10 responses, choose one random from the incoming responses and use it in the message.channel.send section!
Note: Tried, works.